# How to get Var inside onclick function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 variables outside. want to display those 2 variable values inside onclick event.. Cant able to get value using my below code.. please help me to solve this issue. Have to fix this issue in 3 hours.

```
var myCode = "12345";
var myCount = "5"

$('.cols2.continue').html('<a href="#" onClick="test.element=&#39;myCode, myCount &#39;;test.elemName=+myCode +;">Browse</a>');
```

Now, i m getting variable name in place of value.

Thanks

Comment: Look up [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click). Don't add inline event handlers.

Comment: Look into the JavaScript concatenation `+`.

Comment: you need to use string concatenation

Comment: Is this the result of learning jquery without knowing basic js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your jquery would be

```
var myCode = "12345";
var myCount = "5"

$('.continue').html('<a href="#" onClick="test.element=&#39;'+myCode+', '+myCount+' &#39;;test.elemName='+myCode+ ';">Browse</a>');
```

[JsFiddel](http://jsfiddle.net/Amit12x/fsyAd/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Consider *not* HTML mangling:

```
var myCode = function () {
    /* Don't use a string for "code" here either,
       then it can be used as a normal function later on. */
}
var myCount = "5"

var $a = $('<a href="#">Browse</a>')
/* Yay, normal event callback function (and closure)! */ 
$a.click(function () {
    myCode()
    alert(myCount)
})

/* In most cases it's like sufficient just to add the element;
   to replace all content, use .empty().append($a) */
$('.cols2.continue').append($a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var myCode = "12345";
var myCount = "5";

$('.cols2.continue').html('<a href="#" onClick="test.element=&#39;'+myCode+',     '+myCount+'&#39;test.elemName='+myCode +';">Browse</a>');
```

Comment: Thanks all for solve my funny issue... thanks very much